# Read unsigned long long using fscanf()

Tags: c, file, scanf

How do i read a 64-bit unsigned integer from a file? I've got it stored as actual binary data, not a string representation.

Comment: well, you'd use fread then, not fscanf.. since that's for reading from strings.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is it encoded?  Binary numbers usually differ in [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  If you want to assume it's the same as the current host's endianness, you can use `fread` directly.  Otherwise, you'll need to byte-swap it after reading.

For bonus points, assuming you have control over how it's serialized, you could indicate the endianness with some flag or byte order mark.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
FILE * fp = fopen("file.bin", "rb");

uint64_t value;
if (fread(&value, sizeof value, fp) != sizeof value) { /* error */ }

// ...

fclose(fp);
```

If it was you who wrote the data, this should work out of the box. If the data comes from somewhere else, check the documentation of the binary format to account for differences in representation between the serialized format and your platform (e.g. byte swapping may be required).

---

An alternative, pedagogically more useful but less efficient way is to read the data into a buffer and apply your own processing. This is more flexible (e.g. you can deal with crazy endiannesses like 3-2-1-4-7-8-6-5), but probably a lot slower:

```
unsigned char buf[sizeof uint64_t];
if (fread(buf, sizeof buf, fp) != sizeof buf) { /* error */ }
uint64_t leval = buf[0] + (buf[1] << 8) + /* ... */;
uint64_t beval = buf[7] + (buf[6] << 8) + /* ... */;
uint64_t ceval = (buf[0] << 16) + (buf[1] << 8) + buf[2] + (buf[3] << 24) + /* ... */;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

//function to dump hex from file.
void hexdump(const char *const filename)
{
    FILE         *file;
    unsigned char byte;


    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
        return;
    fprintf(stdout, "hexdump of `%s': ", filename);
    while (fread(&byte, 1, 1, file) == 1)
        fprintf(stdout, "0x%02x ", byte);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
}

int main(void) {
    //x64
    //write text, write binary,
    //read text, read binary

    FILE *fout, *filein;
    char *filename_txt = "myfile.txt";  //text filename
    char *filename_bin = "myfile.bin";  //bin filename

    //unsigned long long my64 = 0x1234567887654321;
    //two x64 numbers
    uint64_t my64 = 258;                        //258 (dec) = 102(hex) =  0000 0000 0000 0102 -> 0201 0000 0000 0000 -> 2010000000000000 -> to file
    uint64_t my642 = 1234567891011121314;       //1234567891011121314(dec) = 112210F4B2D230A2 (hex) = 1122 10F4 B2D2 30A2 -> A230 D2B2 F410 2211 -> A230D2B2F4102211 -> to file

    // write as text
    fout = fopen(filename_txt, "wt");
    fprintf(fout, "%" PRIu64 "\n", my64);
    fprintf(fout, "%" PRIu64 "\n", my642);
    fclose(fout);    

    // write as bytes
    fout = fopen(filename_bin, "wb");
    fwrite(&my64, sizeof(my64), 1, fout);
    fwrite(&my642, sizeof(my64), 1, fout);
    fclose(fout);    

    // read as text
    filein = fopen(filename_txt, "rt");
    if(filein==NULL){printf("Cann't open file \"myfile.txt\" for reading...\n");}
    else{
        printf("Try to reading file as text\n");
        char buf[1000];
        while (fgets(buf,1000,filein)!=NULL)
            printf("%s",buf);
        fclose(filein);
    }


    // read as bytes
        /* check that the content of the file is not printable, i.e. not text */
        hexdump(filename_bin);

    filein = fopen(filename_bin, "rb");
    if (filein == NULL){
        printf("Cann't open file \"myfile.bin\" for reading...\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        uint64_t value;
        printf("Try to reading file as bytes\n");
        value = 0;

        while(fread(&value, sizeof(value), 1, filein) == 1){
            fprintf(stdout, "The value read was %" PRIu64 "\n", value);
        }

        fclose(filein);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does this code without an explanation answer the OP's question? Furthermore, you completely ignore the portability issues that lie at the core of the question: type sizes, encoding and endianness may vary from one system to another, so matching `fread` / `fwrite` may not suffice. (`uint64_t` if available is specified as using 2's complement without padding bits, but the endianness is still an issue.)

Comment: Question about read 64-bit number from binary file. Here is example to write 64-bit numbers and read this as text and as binary data (little endian x64).

Answer (score 0):

Someone spoke about portability issues, so I post here modified version with
(unsigned long long). See coments in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>   //this need to working system("pause"); only
                        //system("pause"); need only to don't close window
                        //if program running by double click on exe in windows.
//#include <inttypes.h> //this need to working with uint64_t    and no need to working with (unsigned long long)

//function to dump hex from file.
void hexdump(const char *const filename)
{
    FILE         *file;
    unsigned char byte;


    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
        return;
    fprintf(stdout, "hexdump of `%s': ", filename);
    while (fread(&byte, 1, 1, file) == 1)
        fprintf(stdout, "0x%02x ", byte);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
}

int main(void) {
    //x64
    //write text, write binary,
    //read text, read binary

    FILE *fout, *filein;
    char *filename_txt = "myfile.txt";  //text filename
    char *filename_bin = "myfile.bin";  //bin filename

    //two x64 numbers

    //uint64_t
    //uint64_t my64 = 258;                      //258 (dec) = 102(hex) =  0000 0000 0000 0102 -> 0201 0000 0000 0000 -> 2010000000000000 -> to file
    //uint64_t my642 = 1234567891011121314;    //1234567891011121314(dec) = 112210F4B2D230A2 (hex) = 1122 10F4 B2D2 30A2 -> A230 D2B2 F410 2211 -> A230D2B2F4102211 -> to file

    //unsigned long long x64
    unsigned long long my64 = 1234567887654321; //as 64 bit integer
    unsigned long long my642 = 0x462D53C650DB1; //the same number, as hex

    // write as text
    fout = fopen(filename_txt, "wt");

//uint64_t
//  fprintf(fout, "%" PRIu64 "\n", my64);
//  fprintf(fout, "%" PRIu64 "\n", my642);

//unsigned long long
    fprintf(fout, "%llu%llu\n", my64);
    fprintf(fout, "%llu%llu\n", my642);

    fclose(fout);   

    // write as bytes
    fout = fopen(filename_bin, "wb");
    fwrite(&my64, sizeof(my64), 1, fout);   //write first number
    fwrite(&my642, sizeof(my64), 1, fout);  //write second number
    fclose(fout);   

    // read as text
    filein = fopen(filename_txt, "rt");
    if(filein==NULL){printf("Cann't open file \"myfile.txt\" for reading...\n");}
    else{
        printf("Try to reading file as text\n");
        char buf[1000];
        while (fgets(buf,1000,filein)!=NULL)
            printf("%s",buf); //just print buf as string.
        fclose(filein);
    }


    // read as bytes
        /* check that the content of the file is not printable, i.e. not text */
        hexdump(filename_bin);

    filein = fopen(filename_bin, "rb");
    if (filein == NULL){
        printf("Cann't open file \"myfile.bin\" for reading...\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        //uint64_t value;
        unsigned long long int value;
        printf("Try to reading file as bytes\n");
        value = 0;

        while(fread(&value, sizeof(value), 1, filein) == 1){
//          fprintf(stdout, "The value read was %" PRIu64 "\n", value);     //uint64_t
            fprintf(stdout, "The value read was %llu%llu\n", value);        //unsigned long long
        }

        fclose(filein);
    }

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

1 byte-integers can be writted as binary and readed from binary
if variable have the type - unsigned char.